# Listview inside Cardview using RecyclerView

Tags: android

I want to add a dynamically loading listview inside cardviews arranged in a grid Layout that loads up dynamically according to data present. How can it be done?

All the listviews will be different according to data fetched from the links:

1) http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bTARFsabKG?indent=2 (Used)

OR

2) http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cnWvBVaGoO?indent=2

Supporting code for the same is as below:

Mainactivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    Context context;

    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerView_Adapter;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewLayoutManager;


    FoodItem foodItem;

    ArrayList<FoodItem> items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        foodItem = new FoodItem();

        items = new ArrayList<FoodItem>();

        new ApiFetchOrder().execute("");

        context = getApplicationContext();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);



    }


    public class ApiFetchOrder extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private String JsonResponse = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            JsonResponse = null;

            JSONArray jsonArray = null;

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {

                URL url = new URL("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bTARFsabKG?indent=2");
                Log.d("urlUpadteImage", String.valueOf(url));
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");


                Log.d("urlConnection", String.valueOf(urlConnection));


                InputStream inputstream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputstream == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));

                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    buffer.append(inputLine + "\n");
                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    return null;
                }
                JsonResponse = buffer.toString();

                jsonArray = new JSONArray(JsonResponse);

                Log.v("JsonRes",jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("foodItem").getJSONArray("item1").getString(0));

                //Log.v("JsonResponse",JsonResponse);

                int j=1;
                while(j<=4) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONArray arr = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("foodItem").getJSONArray("item" + j);

                        foodItem.setName(arr.getString(0));
                        foodItem.setQuantity(arr.getString(1));

                        Log.v("JsonArray", arr.getString(0)+arr.getString(1));
                        j++;

                    items.add(foodItem);
                    }
                    j++;
                }


            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {


            //Change 3 to your choice because here 3 is the number of Grid layout Columns in each row.
            recyclerViewLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context,3);

            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);

            recyclerView_Adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(context,items);

            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerView_Adapter);

        }


    }

}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<FoodItem> values;
    Context context1;
    ItemsAdapter listViewAdapter;

    FoodItem foodItem;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context2,ArrayList<FoodItem> values2){

        context1 = context2;

        values= values2;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ListView listView;

        public ViewHolder(View v){

            super(v);

            listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

        View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(context1).inflate(R.layout.item_view,parent,false);


        listViewAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(context1,R.layout.items,values);

        foodItem = new FoodItem();

        return new ViewHolder(view1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Vholder, int position){

        Vholder.listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return values.size();
    }

}
```

ItemsAdapter.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FoodItem> {

    ArrayList<FoodItem> itemList;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;


    public ItemsAdapter(Context context, int resource , ArrayList<FoodItem> objects) {
        super(context, resource , objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        itemList = objects;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            holder.itemName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            holder.itemQuantity = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemQuantity);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        holder.itemName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
        holder.itemQuantity.setText(itemList.get(position).getQuantity());
        return v;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView itemName;
        public TextView itemQuantity;
    }
}
```

FoodItem.java

```
public class FoodItem {
    String Name,Quantity,TableNo;

    public FoodItem(){}

    public FoodItem(String name, String quantity, String tableNo) {
        Name = name;
        Quantity = quantity;
        TableNo = tableNo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return Quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getTableNo() {
        return TableNo;
    }

    public void setTableNo(String tableNo) {
        TableNo = tableNo;
    }
}
```

Layout Files:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

item_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardElevation="7dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="7dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="7dp"
    >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemName"
        tools:text="Item Name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemQuantity"
        tools:text="Quantity"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to use `RecyclerView` instead `ListView`. And put your main `RecyclerView` into `NestedScrollView`. Then you must call `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` for main and nested RecyclerViews. So, I think, this will work and all nested RecyclerViews will be expanded.

Comment: @VladimirParfenov The code is working fine. I just want to know how can I show different data in each of the recycler views according to the JSON data received.

Comment: check this. might help https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view